# JS and Actionscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, extjs

I have build a custom flash player which is embeded in web page using html and javascript extjs framework in the background.

The player is embeded into extjs draggable window into the web page. I know that I can send/recieve variables and trigger events from/to flash player and javascript in the web page.

When I drag the window with the player in it if i drag it fast, cursor goes over the player and the dragging stops. This is because dragging event from javascript stops at the moment when I hover over the flash canvas.

So my question is, is there a way to prevent this from happening?
Is there a way to tell js to continue dragging the window even if the mouse is over the flash canvas?

thanks

Comment: As I understand, Flash content is always on top, overlapping HTML content, that is why it intercepts mouse events. I would think about altering Flash with static image during dragging and showing the Flash content back once the dragging is over.

Comment: :) good advice. Is this achievable in real time?

Comment: Ok tried this way, i.e i put image on top of the player, and switch it when dragging but still when image is on top the dragging stops after mouse hovers over the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the "wmode" param tag nested in the object tag.  Set the value of "wmode" to "transparent".

```
<object ...>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

Or if you are using JavasScript to create the flash using swfobject or similar

```
swfobject.embedSWF('theFile.swf',
            "main-pars-flash_0",
            "480",
            "518",
            "9.0.0",
            "",
            {}, //flashvars 
            {wmode: 'transparent'},  //params
            {} //attributes);
```

more info :http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/transparent-background-swf-file.html